# how can i edit cell values in a datatables.net dataTable

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a small issue. I have a query that i have returned as JSON data and i'm loading that into a datatable from datatables.net. I have values that are 0,1 or 2's and i would like to change these into yes, no or n/a.

I don't know anything about js and i've tried to implement what i read on the website but i still can't get it working. Any help would be appreciated.

This is what i have so far

```
var oTable = $('#test').dataTable({
"aaData": {{ $ecl_staff }},
"sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
"aoColumns": [ 
{ "mDataProp": "id" },
{ "mDataProp": "full_name" },
{ "mDataProp": "user_number" },
{ "mDataProp": "campus" },
{ "mDataProp": "email" },
{ "mDataProp": "mobile" },
{ "mDataProp": "co_ordinator" },
{ "mDataProp": "job_title" },
{ "mDataProp": "contractor" },
{ "mDataProp": "returning" },
{ "sDefaultContent": "id",
"fnRender": function (oObj) { return "<span class='button-group compact'><a         class='button icon-gear with-tooltip modal_link' title='Edit user' href='{{ URL::base() }}/admin/staff/edit_staff/" + oObj.aData['id'] + "'></a> <a class='button icon-card with-tooltip modal_link' title='View Profile' href='{{ URL::base() }}/admin/staff/edit_staff/" + oObj.aData['id'] + "'></a></span>";
                 }
            }
        ],

        "sDom": '<"tbl_tools"CT<"clear">>,<"tbl-tools-searchbox"fl<"clear">>,<"table_content"t>,<"widget-bottom"ip<"clear">>',
            "oTableTools": {
            "sSwfPath": "../swf/copy_cvs_xls_pdf.swf"
            }, 

    });

    $("div.tbl-tools-searchbox select").addClass('blue-gradient glossy replacement'); 
    $("div.tbl_tools").addClass('hidden-on-mobile');                

    $("tfoot input").keyup( function () {
    var id = $(this).attr('id').split("-")[1];
    oTable.fnFilter( this.value, id );
    });
```

The `{ "mDataProp": "returning" }`, data is the column that contains the 0,1 and 2's.
Thanks :)

Comment: would it not be easier to change the data before using it in datatables?

Comment: Hi yes but my mysql skills aren't that great. when i read about if statements in mysql it mentioned something about stored procedures which i'm not doing. thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is very possible
reference - [DataTables.net Column Usage](http://www.datatables.net/usage/columns)

```
var oTable = $('#test').dataTable({
    "aaData": {{ $ecl_staff }},
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    "aoColumnDefs": [ {
        "aTargets": [ 9 ],// index of the returning column
        "mRender": function ( data, type, full ) {
            if(data == 0){
                return "No";
            }
            if(data == 1){
                return "Yes";
            }
            if(data == 2){
                return "N/A";
            }
        }
    } ],
    "aoColumnDefs": [ {
        "aTargets": [ 10 ],// index of the id column
        "mRender": function ( data, type, full ) {
            return "<span class='button-group compact'><a class='button icon-gear with-tooltip modal_link' title='Edit user' href='{{ URL::base() }}/admin/staff/edit_staff/" + data + "'></a> <a class='button icon-card with-tooltip modal_link' title='View Profile' href='{{ URL::base() }}/admin/staff/edit_staff/" + data + "'></a></span>";
        }
    } ],
    "sDom": '<"tbl_tools"CT<"clear">>,<"tbl-tools-searchbox"fl<"clear">>,<"table_content"t>,<"widget-bottom"ip<"clear">>',
    "oTableTools": {
        "sSwfPath": "../swf/copy_cvs_xls_pdf.swf"
     }
});
```